# Create a excel chart only with axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I want to create an excel chart with only the axes namely x axis and y axis  with x axis values ranging from 1 to 100 and y axis values ranging from 1 to 100

Is this possible? If so how to do it?

Note: The method prescribed for doing this should not to refer to any data for doing this, I want to directly create the chart by using commands.

I am using Excel 2010

Comment: What commands? VBA? Automation?

Comment: I mean, if you tell me how to do this via GUI, I can record a macro and know the command. If u can give me the vba code, that would be fine too. I searched a lot over the web, couldnt find any resource for this.

Comment: Moreover, I want to do this because,  I want only the lines or bars to change when I select different data and not the whole chart itself. I have to write a code for that.

Comment: I think there is no possibility to have a chart without reference to any data. Consider putting a single point outside your range. If you mark any two cells that are empty, this would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put in 100 bits of data, all set to 0, to make a "blank" chart with 100 data points. You'll have to adjust the y-axis range to show 0-100. Record doing this as a macro, and it will provide that starting point you're asking about.

Comment: It's enough to put one point of data. The axes ranges can be adjusted in chart settings.

Comment: Good point. @Kira, right click on the axis on the chart, and choose axis options to change the scale (to 100). You'll have to do this for both axis.

Comment: This point can be even empty, so it does not affect your worksheet.